# The Physical Sense of Vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, intuition

I'm learning vectors now. I can solve difficult problems well enough, but there is something I can't wrap my head around.

AB + BC = AC

If AB = 10 and BC = 9,
Would that mean that AC which seems much shorter will have the magnitude of 19?

[image]

Comment: A vector is not a number the vector AB is not equal to 10 and the vector BC is not equal to 9. Those numbers represent the magnitudes of the vectors.

Comment: See [Vectors Addition and subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AC$ will *not* have magnitude $19$!

Remember, $AB = B - A$ and $BC = C - B$. Hence,

$AC = AB + BC = (B - A) + (C - B) = C - A$

$C - A$ will be the short vector from $A$ to $C$.

For a simple counter-example that vector magnitudes to not add up like regular numbers, consider $X = (1, 0)$. We know that $\vert X \vert = 1$.

However, $|X + (-X)| = |(1, 0) - (1, 0)| = | (0, 0)| = 0$, whereas

$
|X| + |-X| = |(1, 0) + |(-1, 0)| = 1 + 1 = 2
$

Hence, in general $|A + B| \neq |A| + |B|$.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not true that "the magnitude of the sum is the sum of the magnitudes."